# Zooming using GWT MouseWheelEvent too fast on Mac using trackpad

Tags: gwt, canvas, mousewheel

I am capturing a MouseWheelEvent for zooming in/out on a canvas.  This works fine using an actual mouse wheel on Windows 7 under Firefox, Chrome, and IE, but on a Mac OS X, using track pad causes zooming to happen much too quickly.

I've seen other solutions normalizing the wheel delta using native JavaScript that involve the detail retrieved from the mouse wheel event, but is there a way to do this using java with GWT which only provides access to the wheel delta?

Answer (score 0):

Wheel delta variations can also be changed through operating system.

Can you confirm that it is only your site that is scrolling too fast?

Can you set a maximum scroll speed?

Handle scroll events through Jquery or another plugin to normalize input cross browser?